# entering data in sql database through asp

Tags: asp-classic

```
pass=session("password")
Set objIns=server.CreateObject("adodb.connection")
objIns.Open session("Psrconnect")

inspass="Insert into passwords(pass) values ('&pass&')"
objIns.Execute(inspass)
```

i dont know what should be the syntax to pass the value stored in the variable. with this syntax, the value entered in the database is &pass&.
can anyone plz help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this line

```
inspass="Insert into passwords(pass) values ('&pass&')"
```

should be

```
inspass="Insert into passwords(pass) values ('" & pass & "')"
```

Note the double quotes after and before each apostrophe.

Comment: i am using
session("password")=y
where y has some value. is it the correct syntax. i am not sure if the session value is getting stored or not.

Comment: when i try your method. the entry goes empty
thats why i was wondering if the value itself is getting stored in the session